# Register form submitting when reCAPTCHA isn't validated

Tags: php, recaptcha

I added reCAPTCHA to my registration form and when I tested the page, I noticed I can still register a new account without verifying using reCAPTCHA. When I leave one of the text boxes blank I receive "Please verify that you are Human." This message is supposed to appear when a user fills out the form and forgets to verify. I tried many different if statements provided by stack overflow and other websites and the issues still weren't solved. I also tried messing around with my form with "method" and "action".

Here is my registration form

```
<?php include('server.php') ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register for Redchan</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.php" title="Home"><img alt="4chan" src="/image/pepe-popcorn.gif" width="300" height="120"></a>
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Register for Redchan</h2>
    </div>
    <?php
    //Check for form submission
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        //Get form submission data
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];


        //Set verification information for the Google reCAPTCHA API
        $secretKey = "----------------------------------";
        $responseKey = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        $userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        //Call Google reCAPTCHA API
        $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretKey&response=$responseKey&remoteip=$userIP";
        $response = file_get_contents($url);

        //Decode API response and generate response
        $verification = json_decode($response, true);
        if ($verification['success'])
            echo "<p>Verification success!</p>";
        else
            echo "<p>Please verify that you are a Human.</p>";
    }
?>
    <form method="post" action="register.php">

        <?php include('errors.php'); ?>

        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password_1">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Confirm password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password_2">
        </div>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="-------------------------------"></div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn" name="reg_user">Register</button>
        </div>
        <p>
            Already a member? <a href="login.php">Sign in</a>
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the captcha field itself to required which by default is not.

You could try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var $recaptcha = document.querySelector('#g-recaptcha-response');

        if ($recaptcha) {
            $recaptcha.setAttribute("required", "required");
        }
    };
</script>
```